# Android:I wanna make the children get the OnClickListener,

Tags: android

I have a parent `LinearLayout` in which has some `ImageView`s, now I set `OnCLickListener` on the parent layout. How can I make the children ImageViews get the click listener?

Could something like this work?:

```
parent.setOnCLickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == childImageViewA) {
              //...........
        }
         //..........
     }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just set listeners on the child views instead of the parent. If you want a listener on a specific view you should assign it to that view.

Comment: yeah,thanks.I just wanna know if there is some possible way to achieve this.:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
parent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v;

            for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
                if(child == childImageViewA) {
                    //Do something with child
                }
            }
        }

});
```

Comment: eh,thanks.But what I need is:When the user click the parent layout,and actually the mouse is on the child view.So I wanna the childview react the onclick event.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method, like, handleClickEvent(), in the child view which you can call inside the For loop in @Bobbake4 's code above.  Ofcourse you'd need to cast it to the Child View's type, to be able to call the method that you wrote.

Hope this makes sense!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not the biggest fan of running through all the children to get the parent's callback to fire.

I would have childImageViewA.setOnClickListener(parent) where parent implements OnClickListener interface.

This approach requires no loop.